# Can I import an entire folder into After Effects and/or Premiere, in such a way that newly-created files will be imported automatically?

Tags: workflow, premiere

One of the most maddening things about my workflow in After Effects and Premiere is that whenever I record a new piece of footage (e.g. recording a new .mp4 in OBS) or create a new image asset (e.g. saving a new .png from Photoshop), I have to manually import *that specific file* into my project.

It's a given that anybody who's working in these programs is going to have the source assets for their project organized in a single, sensible folder structure on disk. For example:

- `myproject/myproject.prproj`
- `myproject/footage/010_somefile.mp4`
- `myproject/footage/020_anotherfile.mp4`

Then, within `myproject.prpoj`, I've imported those assets in a way that mirrors their structure on disk: I make a bin called "footage", then import the video files from my `footage` directory into that bin.

If I record a new file called `030_yetanotherfile.mp4` and place it into my footage directory, I then have to take the extra step of manually importing it into Premiere (or After Effects, depending on where I'm working). I've already put thought and effort into how my source files are structured on disk, so it's extremely frustrating to have to waste time manually keeping my project files in sync.

Is there a way to have Premiere and/or After Effects automatically import newly-added source files? I just want to be able to import a *folder* and have the program automatically pick up changes from disk, as opposed to having to manually pick individual files ad nauseum.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Pro IO plugin allows you to have "live bins", so as you add a file, it appears in After Effects etc.. I haven't used it though.
https://aescripts.com/pro-io/